# Problem with importing modules in Python shell

Tags: python

I am a novice in programming and I have just started learning Python. I have a problem with importing modules in Python 3.7.0 shell. The import works fine in cmd but shows the error message as shown below, when I try to import it in Python Shell.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
  import Script
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Script'
```

As I am a beginner, I would kindly request an elaborate explanation.

Comment: Which `pyshell` are you using, or what program are you using to access it?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming Script is your own module.
When you are importing from the shell, you are probably in the same directory as `script.py`.
When you are importing it from a script, you should make sure your script is running in the same directory where your `script.py` module is located.

Comment: Also note filenames and Python are case sensitive, so `script.py` would import as `script`, not `Script`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a "Script" module, it should be either in the current working directory or in the Python path. The directories of the Python path can be listed:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You can append a directory to `sys.path` to extend the path if necessary.